# delete values from array that corresponds to a specific elements of another array

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = array([1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.])
b = np.array([[-1, 1], [-2, 1.8], [-3, -2], [-1.5, 1.5], [4, 6], [-3, 2.3]])
```

I want to delete points the ones correspond to 0
this means the output should be this:

```
b = np.array([[-1, 1], [-3, -2], [4, 6]])
```

I tried this:

```
for i, j in zip(a, b):
  ind = np.where(i == 0.0) 
  b = np.delete(b, ind, axis=0)
print(b)
```

but this deletes randomly. can pls someone help?

Comment: Think in terms of which rows of `b` you want to keep.

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't work, because once you remove an element from array, indexing changes. Try this:

```
# create empty numpy array
result = np.empty((0,2), float)

# append if case matches
for i in range(len(a)):
    if(a[i] == 0):
        result = np.append(result, [b[i]], axis = 0)
```

or simply print:

```
print(b[a==0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
b=b[a!=0,:]
```

Comment: can you please explain why rows and not columns? to understand more how it works @Alex Alex

Comment: See indexing array in numpy: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html